# LED for High frequency/blinking application

Tags: led

Which parameter in the datasheet of the LED defines the turn on time and turn off time?
What kind of LEDs are used for high speed switching applications?
Thank you

Comment: Define 'high frequency', and type of signal. And give an outline of application.

Comment: I don't think many LEDs will have a max frequency specification as they are intended as light sources or indicators, not for high speed data transfer for example. For that lasers are used.

Comment: *"LED needs to drive and at high frequency"* Did you broadly mean switching times?

Comment: Depending on your definition of high speed, LEDs can be use.  I have an old video camera with an infrared transmitter and receiver rig that connects to the TV.  The receiver connects to the TV, and the camera has the transmitter built in and transmits the video to the TV during playback.  Standard PAL video has a bandwidth of 8 MHz. That would count as high frequency in my book.  I wouldn't want to use a white LED, though, since they use an LED to energize a phosphor.  The phosphor won't stop glowing immediately when the LED goes off.

Comment: related http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24287/can-an-led-achieve-full-brightness-in-40-%C2%B5s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which parameter in the datasheet of the LED defines the turn on time
>   and turn off time?

Normally that will be rise time or fall time. If not listed, presume the LED to be poor at data transmission.

> What kind of LEDs are used for high speed switching applications?

I use laser LEDs to transmit data at high speed but my version of high speed is only about 600 Mbps whereas a lot of laser LEDs can go well into the Gbps. The best standard LED I reviewed was good for about 100 Mbps. It was an Osram SFH4750 (infra red).

Answer (score 5):

I got more info from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/118141/high-frequency-blinking-leds-and-sensor-for-that) which is relevant until more details from the OP is available

> Pretty much any LED available can be operated at far higher blink
>   frequencies than 1 KHz: White LEDs or others which use a secondary
>   phosphor would be the slowest, often topping off in the 1 to 5 MHz
>   region, while standard off-the-shelf primary LEDs (red, blue, green,
>   IR, UV etc) are typically rated at a cut-off frequency of 10 to 50 MHz
>   (sine wave).
>
> The cut-off frequency is the maximum frequency at which light emission
>   drops to half the initial intensity. Few LED datasheets list the
>   cut-off frequency, but the rise time and fall time of the LED are more
>   common - unfortunately not for the specific datasheet linked in the
>   question.
>
> In practice, one would be safe in topping off at one tenth the cut-off
>   frequency for a well shaped square pulse, so 1 MHz visible light
>   communication is very reasonable. As long as LEDs are SMD or with very
>   short lead lengths, and PCB track / component lead capacitance and
>   inductance are kept to a minimum, **driving an LED to 1 MHz is feasible**
>   without complex pulse-shaping drive circuits.